# null object reference in master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some controls inside my master page, and i want to acces them from its related c# clas..

For instance i have:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch" runat="server" 
                 onselectedindexchanged="ddlSearch_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

and i can acces it when writing code, so "it sees its properties ok".

But at runtime i received

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Do u know why?

I also tried to find it like:

```
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder =
        (ContentPlaceHolder)this.FindControl("ContentHead");
    if (mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
    {
        DropDownList ddlSearch =
             (DropDownList)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("ddlSearch");
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            utils.fillDDLSearch(ddlSearch);
    }
```

but it gives null too....which is really strange...

I tried with another object (an asp Image control, but exactly the same problem.
All it's ok at compiling time but gives null at runtime ALTHOUGH IT correctly finds out the content place holder.

Does anybody know the problem?

**The error:**

---

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

Comment: Can you post the code that is throwing the null reference exception?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is strongly type the association between your pages and your master page.  In the Page ascx add this line to the top:
    <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"  %>
where ~/MasterPage.master is a refernce to your actual master page.

Then in your page you will be able to access any control, properties, etc by using:
    Master.[PropertyNameHere] minus the the '[]'.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi, Probably you missed this from my post: "i want to acces them from its related c# clas..". So i am not on the other Page which inherits the Master one, but on the page behind the Master: MasterPage.master.cs

Comment: If you want to access a dropdownlist that is on the MasterPage in the codebehind for the MasterPage, you should be able to access it directly (utils.fillDDLSearch(ddlSearch);).  You shouldn't need to FindControl on the page.  
  
Why are you searching for it in a ContentPlaceHolder?  Is the DropDownList actually in the ContentPlaceHolder?

Comment: Exactly....I agree with this, so i tried to accest it directly first...All was ok on compiling, but not at runtime... I tried with other object too, from the Master Page, and the same behaviour...That's why i tried to find it with the content place holder. (gives null as well...)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put this components in a user control and handle the behaviour there.
And put the user control in the master page.

However the problem remains unclear:
- why a control in the master page cannot be accesed from the masterpage.cs directly...?